# Service Fabric ConfigurePortCertificate error AlreadyExists

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've deployed my SSL cert to my cluster, it exists in the correct store on each VM. However, when I try and publish my application to the cluster, it fails.

Event Viewer on the VM says `ConfigurePortCertificate: httpsPort=443, certStoreName My, certfindvalue {SSLCertFingerPrint}, error AlreadyExists`

What does this mean?

Comment: I believe this is because I was trying to bind two different certificates to the same endpoint. Clarification would be welcomed, so leaving this open for discussion.

Comment: Did you see [this thread](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-web-reference-app/issues/3) from about 10 months ago? Same error you get, but I think for a different reason. I think you are right that adding two certs to same port will cause this error (saw your other post, guess it is related?).